# Using n2cms, How do I stop a div from automatically wrapped around my user controls

Tags: c#, content-management-system

I'm trying to create a part which is essentially a list

```
<ul>
    <n2:DroppableZone ID="zoneSlideshowItems" ZoneName="SlideshowItems" AllowExternalManipulation="true" runat="server"></n2:DroppableZone>
</ul>
```

I have another part that i drop multiple times onto the above zone:

```
<li>
    <a href="<%= CurrentItem.Link %>">
        <img src="<%=CurrentItem.ImageUrl %>" alt="<%= CurrentItem.Title %>" />
        <div class="overlayBox">
            <h1><%= CurrentItem.OverlayHeader %></h1>
            <p><%= CurrentItem.OverlayText %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlayBoxBack">
        </div>

    </a>       
</li>
```

However when i look at the page source, its adding a div around each

element that i drop onto the zone:

```
<div class='uc slideshowItem'> <<<< That Guy!!

<li>
    <a href="http://gigpig.fm">
        <img src="/Upload/skal.jpg" alt="Anthony is Jacinta" />
        <div class="overlayBox">
            <h1>Anthony</h1>
            <p>im trying to tell you something</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlayBoxBack">

        </div>

    </a>       
</li>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to stop that div from being generated?

Cheers!